# Tikz concept picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a figure like image below using Tikz. Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Trying how, exactly? That is, what have you tried, what's the problem and where's the code we can use to reproduce what you've got?

Comment: The circle node puts the text into a rectangle at fits the circle to the box.  You might consider using shapepar to fit the text into a more rounded shape with a normal node, then draw a separate circle around the text only.

Comment: I reckon the original paper could be referenced. The figure was originally made available in: Sivarajah, U., Kamal, M.M., Irani, Z. and Weerakkody, V. 2017. Critical analysis of Big Data challenges and analytical methods. Journal of Business Research. 70, pp.263–286.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
every node/.style={
  align=center
},
challenge/.style={
  shape=circle,
  line width=0.2cm,
  draw,
  execute at begin node=\begin{minipage}[t][3.5cm]{3.5cm},
  execute at end node=\end{minipage}
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round, line join=round, >=latex]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=lifecycle]
\begin{scope}
\node [challenge] (data) {
    \textbf{Data}
    \\
    \textbf{\textit{Challenges}}
    \medskip
    \\
    Data challenges are the \\
    group of the challenges \\
    related to the characteristics \\
    of the data itself
};
\foreach \characteristic [count=\i, evaluate={\a=\i*20+100;}] in
 {Volume, Velocity, Variety, Variability, Veracity, Visualisation, Value}{
 \node at (\a:3.5cm) [rotate=\a+180, anchor=east] {\characteristic};
 \draw [very thick] (\a-10:5.5cm) -- (\a-10:3.5cm) 
   arc (\a-10:\a+10:3.5cm) -- (\a+10:5.5cm);
}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift=(0:10cm)]
\node [challenge] (process) {
    \textbf{Process}
    \\
    \textbf{\textit{Challenges}}
    \medskip
    \\
    Process challenges include \\
    all those challenges \\
    encountered while \\
    processing the data
};
\foreach \characteristic [count=\i, evaluate={\a=\i*20+100;}] in
 {Data acquisition \\\& warehousing, Data mining \& \\ cleansing}{
 \node at (\a:3.5cm) [rotate=\a+180, anchor=east] {\characteristic};
 \draw [very thick] (\a-10:5.5cm) -- (\a-10:3.5cm) 
   arc (\a-10:\a+10:3.5cm) -- (\a+10:5.5cm);
}
\foreach \characteristic [count=\i, evaluate={\a=-\i*20;}] in
 {Data aggregation \\\& integration, Analysis \& \\ modelling, Data \\ interpretation}{
 \node at (\a:3.5cm) [rotate=\a, anchor=west] {\characteristic};
 \draw [very thick] (\a-10:5.5cm) -- (\a-10:3.5cm) 
   arc (\a-10:\a+10:3.5cm) -- (\a+10:5.5cm);
}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift=(0:20cm)]
\node [challenge] (management) {
    \textbf{Management}
    \\
    \textbf{\textit{Challenges}}
    \medskip
    \\
    Management challenges \\
    tackle e.g., privacy, \\
    security, governance and \\
    lack of skills related to \\
    understanding and \\
    analysing data
    };
\foreach \characteristic [count=\i, evaluate={\a=70-\i*20;}] in
 {Privacy, Security, Data governance, Data \& information \\ sharing, 
 Cost/operational \\ expenditures, Data ownership}{
 \node at (\a:3.5cm) [rotate=\a, anchor=west] {\characteristic};
 \draw [very thick] (\a-10:5.5cm) -- (\a-10:3.5cm) 
   arc (\a-10:\a+10:3.5cm) -- (\a+10:5.5cm);
}
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\draw [ultra thick] (data.south) to [bend right] (process.south);
\draw [ultra thick] (process.north) to [bend left] (management.north);
\draw [ultra thick, <->] (lifecycle.north west) -- (lifecycle.north east)
  node [midway, above] {Data lifecycle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: data managment lifecycle]